# ScalaTest with Microsoft Edge?

Tags: selenium, microsoft-edge, scalatest

I am using ScalaTest for testing with Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer, e.g.

```
class LoginSpec extends FlatSpec with MustMatchers with InternetExplorer
{
  val host = "http://localhost:8080/"

  "The foobar home page" must "have the correct title" in
    {
      go to (host)
      pageTitle must be("hello world")
    }    
}
```

My dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
        <artifactId>scalatest_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-beta3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**Is it possible to use ScalaTest for testing with Microsoft Edge?**

I can see that there is a class `org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver` in `org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java` and a respective [executable](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/).

Comment: Have you checked this https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/issues/1617 ?

Comment: That page seems to be about version mismatch problems.